# Remove the white "frame" that occurs when the interface flips?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiinterfaceorientation

I have a view with a black background, when I flip the device and the interface flips with it a white pixelated "frame" appears around the black view during the animation, and then the frame disappears when the interface settles.

This "frame" seem to be part of, or a consequence of the animation, is there any known way of solving this issue?

Comment: I don't know if it helps, but have you tried setting a background color to UIWindow as well, in your AppDelegate?

Comment: Tried that now, did not make any difference :(

Comment: Argh I'm an idiot, that DID solve my problem! Thank you Paul!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution by Paul Peelen:

Setting the UIWindow background color to black, in the AppDelegate, solved the problem :)

```
[[self window] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```